# Contribuir com sua experiência, é melhor do que fazer criticas?

Tags: debate, respostas, comunidade, voto-contra

Respondi uma questão: [Como inverter datas no php, independente do formato?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21774/6026), e com a minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21795/6026) eu não tinha colocado realmente um verificação de datas (inclusive o coloquei para que a mesma fique com esse tipo de verificação), só tive a preocupação de inverte julgando que a data já viria nos dois formatos triviais `d/m/Y` e `Y-m-d`. Um op entrou e fez criticas a maioria das respostas e depois no final respondeu a pergunta com essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21905/6026), que está correta.

A critica colocado aos demais usuários seria desmotivante e poderia afugentar-los ?

Colocar um lembrete dizendo: será que poderia colocar uma rotina de checagem de Data para melhorar a sua resposta, não iria contribuir mais ao SOPT ?

O OP disse:  ***eu prefiro participar mais ativamente do StackOverflow original, onde busca-se a excelência e não reputação***, nós aqui não buscamos a mesma coisa ?

Comment: Não entendo nada de PHP, mas... Ele fez criticas pertinentes e aparentemente válidas nas outras respostas e adicionou uma própria que acredita ser melhor que as demais. Não vejo problema nenhum nisso, é algo que eu faria naturalmente. As críticas foram totalmente técnicas e não me pareceram atacar de forma alguma os autores das outras respostas. Não consigo ler elas como "desmotivantes". E se ele tem uma solução que é em algum fator melhor que todas as já postadas, não tem porque não postar. Enfim, eu não vejo o que há de ruim na forma como ele agiu.

Comment: A resposta dele não é a melhor, isso tudo vai depender da versão do PHP que estiver no servidor ou em produção, e por isso mesmo que eu postei esse questionamento, visto que esses dias atrás eu compartilhei com outros usuários para que a resposta dada por mim fosse mais enriquecedora, @GuilhermeBernal ninguém pode vir e ter um posicionamento desse, se ele tem uma resposta melhor deveria ter colocado sim, com certeza, e poderia nela explicar porque a dele é a mais correta! Apesar de achar que tem uma igualzinha.

Comment: Na minha opinião negativar alguém com o comentário "-1 por achar que a sua solução é boa, mas, op não sabe dividir experiência" está mais contrária ao objetivo do StackOverflow do que negativar uma resposta que, apesar de funcionar, não é tecnicamente boa - deixa claro que é um viés pessoal. Algumas respostas possuem falhas graves de assumir algo que elas não validam. A central de ajuda do SO é bem clara no que diz respeito a negativar/positivar respostas: o objetivo é a excelência. Não há necessidade de comentar uma resposta pedindo uma melhoria: o voto serve exatamente pra isso.

Comment: A propósito: a versão mínima suportada do PHP hoje em dia é a 5.3. Em pouco tempo logo será a 5.4, uma vez que a 5.6 está para sair. Qualquer servidor que use uma versão inferior a 5.3 está sujeito a graves falhas de segurança. Por isso nem coloquei que minha resposta depende do PHP 5.3: esta é a versão mínima recomendável.

Comment: @PauloFreitas, a sua questão não está bem completa por causa desse item, e por isso eu tirei um ponto da sua questão, e só lembrando que isso não é realidade em servidores com PHP a maioria é abaixo desse 5.3 e falha de segurança você está correta, mas, os principais culpados não são os desenvolvedores e sim as hospedagens!

Comment: @HarryPotter Desconheço qualquer serviço de hospedagem sério que use versão do PHP inferior a 5.3. O PHP 5.3 foi lançado há 5 anos e desde que o PHP 5.5 foi lançado  há 1 ano o PHP 5.2 deixou de ser suportado e disponibilizado para download. Os grandes players da indústria de hospedagem já oferecem o PHP 5.5 há um bom tempo.

Comment: @PauloFreitas, OK, com você mesmo disse você desconhece ...

Comment: @HarryPotter Creio que te perguntar por algum exemplo fuja do que se está sendo discutido, pois fundamentalmente, não importa... O fato é que o PHP 5.3 hoje é referência. Tão logo será o PHP 5.4. Quem usa uma versão inferior ao PHP 5.3 hoje assume por si próprio a incompatibilidade com o conteúdo que encontra na web... A menos que o autor da pergunta especifique a versão do software em uso, toda resposta deve ter como a base uma versão estável mínima deste, que no caso do PHP, hoje, é justamente a 5.3.

Comment: @PauloFreitas você está certo de todas as formas, fique tranquilo, porque a discussão acabou, infelizmente acabou para mim, visto que o True === PauloFreitas !!! Desculpe a amolação!

Comment: Nossa, enquanto estava escrevendo uma resposta (em caráter geral) fui vendo a discussão escalar depressa... Vamos acalmar os ânimos, por favor! :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr você tem razão, mas, eu não poderia de comentar isso, pelo fato de achar que os comentários foram ásperos.

Comment: O problema que vejo aqui é que está se misturando uma discordância em relação aos **fatos** com uma discordância em relação ao **tom** ([referência](http://destinatariotheo.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/how-to-disagree-traducao/)). Ambos os aspectos são relevantes, e é preciso conciliá-los (i.e. agir com civilidade e ao mesmo tempo ter compromisso com a verdade factual).

Comment: Concordo com você @mgibsonbr: mas, essa resposta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1572/6026 resume o que eu penso sobre o ocorrido.

Comment: Ainda bem que ninguém pensou em começar a distribuir "-1 por não ter comentado o código". :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, foi bom esta discussão ter sido trazida para o Meta pois eu não queria gerar ainda mais *buzz* nos comentários da pergunta em questão e até acho que o limite de caracteres não seria suficiente.

Pois bem, eu também postei uma resposta, e também fui negativado com a justificativa:

> "-1 Por assumir que irá receber uma entrada esperada sem validar se ela é de fato o que se espera."

E que de fato **está correta**. Meu código de fato não trata o caso de um input indevido de data.

Na minha opinião, isto pode sim ser considerado uma inconsistência na resposta, mas depende do caso. Eu por exemplo, dificilmente vou pegar uma resposta para a minha pergunta e jogar no meu código sem olhar pra traz. Na minha concepção o ideal é adaptá-la as minhas necessidades, melhorá-la e deixa-lá redonda para rodar no meu código.

Tendo isso em mente, eu não espero uma solução 100% a prova de balas para a minha pergunta, mas sim uma solução **que me ajude a entender o problema e que o solucione**. Se eu perguntei qual o caminho para ir de carro de Minas Gerais para São paulo é **exatamente** isto que eu quero saber. Não que eu "não posso sair antes de colocar o cinto, não posso passar do limite da via em que eu vou estar andando, tenho que tomar cuidado com os radares, devo andar de farol baixo, etc". Este tipo de coisa não faz parte da pergunta. São questões que quem responde pode até levantar, mas sera que são diretamente relevantes para a resposta?

Se estas questões de segurança são importantes? Claro que são, e muito. Mas se a cada vez que alguém te perguntar o caminho para o posto de gasolina mais próximo você ficar 10 minutos explicando direção defensiva para a pessoa, você vai estar perdendo seu tempo e o dela.

Vejam bem, eu não estou dizendo que segurança deva ser deixada de lado. Só estou dizendo que você, ao responder uma pergunta simples com uma resposta concisa, pressupõe que quem perguntou saiba o que fazer com aquela resposta.

Eu também não estou dizendo que não se deve negativar respostas erradas ou incompletas. Eu encorajo isso, se a minha resposta está errada, ao receber uma negativada (junto com um comentário detalhando o motivo) eu me forço a aprender mais sobre o assunto para melhorar minha resposta, e consequentemente aumento meu conhecimento. Só acho um pouco complicado negativar uma resposta direta por que você acha que a sua é mais abrangente. Se a sua resposta é melhor ela naturalmente vai receber mais votos e ser escolhida como a correta, não há necessidade de negativar as outras que **resolvem o problema**, mas não são tão completas.

A maioria das respostas do SO não são 100% a prova de brechas de segurança, e eu agradeço por isso, do contrário perguntas do tipo: *"Como eu faço um INSERT no banco de dados?"*. Seriam respondidas com Bíblias em PDF ou links da Amazon para livros de segurança ao invés de respostas na própria página.

Comment: Compartilho da mesma idéia! e foi o que eu fiz na minha resposta!

Comment: Sobre este ponto, minha opinião: O StackOverflow há muito tem se tornado uma das principais fontes de conhecimento e, por conta disto, é tido como referência. Sendo uma referência, é indispensável que haja acurácia em seu conteúdo. Em face disso é essencial que a comunidade mantenha a qualidade das respostas com o voto. Muitas pessoas chegam ao SO por sites de busca à fim de resolver um determinado problema, e uma resposta ruim pode gerar resultados catastróficos.

Comment: +1 em especial pelo "se a minha resposta está errada, ao receber uma negativada (junto com um comentário detalhando o motivo) eu me forço a aprender mais sobre o assunto para melhorar minha resposta, e consequentemente aumento meu conhecimento". Se mais pessoas pensassem assim, muita coisa seria melhor, e muita discussão boba evitada.

Comment: Sobre o caso em específico, veja que a resposta mais bem votada em questão não sugeriu algo que pudesse gerar problema. Algumas respostas, por outro lado, propuseram um uso particular que, se "copiada e colada" em produção, poderia gerar resultados catastróficos num ambiente inseguro. Que a pergunta em si foi ruim, como tu bem apontou nos comentários da tua resposta, disso não há do que discordar.

Comment: @PauloFreitas Concordo, até certo ponto. É preciso colocar as coisas em perspectiva, se "uma resposta ruim pode gerar resultados catastróficos" - e às vezes pode mesmo - então votar contra é pouco: é necessário comentar, trazer ao meta, sinalizar... mas [só quando de fato a medida se justifica](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1118/215). Vi que na pergunta linkada o OP perguntou "independente do formato de entrada", de modo que sua atitude de chamar à atenção à validação foi, na minha opinião, acertada. Mas se é uma omissão grave não tocar nesse ponto numa resposta, não sei dizer.

Comment: @PauloFreitas a minha resposta é um dos vários meios para o mesmo fim. Existem respostas mais completas do que a minha? Existem, e eu [já votei na que acho melhor](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21789/1754), inclusive eu marcaria ela como a correta. Agora se o fato da minha resposta ter sido marcada como correta está te deixando com a pulga atras da orelha, você deveria perguntar para o OP o motivo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Já eu acho que a pergunta dele ficou aberta a interpretações no sentido de "independente do formato de entrada". Se ler os comentários lá na minha resposta vai entender melhor.

Comment: @Kazzkiq Concordo. Afinal, "fazer conversão de formatos" e "validar uma entrada" são duas coisas diferentes: passos importantes numa mesma tarefa, mas ainda assim independentes.

Comment: Esse é o ponto X da questão, atribui `-1` em respostas que não estão erradas, mas, sim pela compreensão o input é do tipo informado na própria questão.

Comment: @Kazzkiq Tua resposta ter sido aceita como correta pelo OP não me deixa com pulga atrás da orelha... Quem decide é ele e assim como também ocorre no SOen, nem sempre a resposta escolhida é a melhor resposta. O fato d'eu também ter negativado tua resposta, muito além da pergunta mal feita, está na resposta "mal dada": ela assume coisas que não valida. Imagine que sua resposta seja usada num sistema que irá receber a data do usuário sem validar antes. Se ela não receber o dado da forma que está esperando, o resultado será catastrófico. E para o SO, que é uma fonte de referência, isso é ruim.

Comment: Sou da exata mesma opinião do @mgibsonbr e é por isso que eu fico perceptivelmente alterado quando me negativam sem motivo ou justificativa. Daí eu vou no stack em questão e cutuco com um comentário sutil. Negativar é pouco! Fazer unicamente porque se pode fazê-lo é extremamente errado. Se você negativa e justifica o motivo, não só você mostra que você REALMENTE sabe o porquê de você estar negativando, como você ainda contribui para o crescimento tanto de quem respondeu quanto do SOPT como um todo.

Answer (score 13):

## Sobre votos negativos

Qualquer usuário tem o direito de negativar sua resposta se assim achar necessário. Há exceções, como em guerra de votos ou criando um perfil falso para burlar o sistema.

Em tese, o SO funciona como uma democracia. A ideia é que mesmo que haja "injustiça" por um lado, a maioria irá fazer a "justiça" se fazer valer.

Como na vida real, nem tudo é perfeito, mas tenho visto que no geral isso funciona.

Portanto, todos nós temos que saber receber votos negativos, "justos" ou "injustos". Faz parte.

## Como usuários votam

Neste pouco tempo de SO pude observar alguns dos padrões de usuários ao votar:

- Os que votam contra ou a favor de acordo com o usuário e não de acordo com a resposta
- Os que votam igual outros já votaram
- Os que só votam positivo em tudo pela "boa intenção" de quem responde
- Os que respondem e negativam todas as outras respostas para tentar se sair melhor
- Os que negativam e não dizem o motivo

Eu considero todos os padrões acima ruins porque não ajudam as respostas ruins a melhorar nem as boas respostas a "brilhar".

Enfim, acho importante comentar isso tanto para quem vota refletir sobre sua motivação e para quem recebe entender que nem sempre dá para esperar uma recepção completamente "justa".

## Sendo negativado com motivo

Ser negativado é ruim, mas a gente se acostuma.

Às vezes o voto negativo vem junto com um comentário. Embora às vezes possamos nos sentir ofendidos, veja isso de outra maneira: você tem uma chance de melhorar.

> *Quem avisa amigo é.*

Reflita sobre a sua resposta. Se realmente for ruim, estude as demais respostas ou pesquise novamente e edite a sua resposta para melhorá-la.

Avise quem comentou. Se o usuário retirar o voto negativo, ótimo! No pior caso você aprendeu algo.

## Sendo negativado sem motivo

Se alguém acompanhar minha reputação no SO desde o início vai ver (como sempre menciono) que levei muita "paulada" por aí.

Veja [uma resposta minha com 2 votos negativos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2077/227). Devo ter gastado mais ou menos umas duas horas para propor **três** alternativas viáveis para o OP e não ganhei um único pontinho de reputação.

Injusto? Eu acho que sim, mas considero a resposta boa o suficiente para ajudar alguém que visite a página posteriormente.

Se você tem confiança na sua resposta, deixe lá pensando que ela vai ajudar muita gente (que provavelmente nem tem cadastro no site e não vai votar por ela).

## Sobre perfeccionistas

Muitas vezes tentamos simplesmente resolver o problema do OP de uma maneira simples sem refletir sobre possíveis impactos. Isso é comum quando a questão não tem detalhes sobre o contexto onde o código será usado. Então é comum algum usuário mais perfeccionista enxergar algum problema e negativar.

Creio ter sido esse o caso na questão em discussão.

Nesse caso, eu tomaria uma das seguintes atitudes:

- **Excluiria** a resposta se achasse que ela não acrescenta em nada em relação às outras e não tem solução ou não tenho tempo para editá-la
- **Editaria** a resposta para corrigir o problema apontado se fosse viável
- **Colocaria um aviso** sobre o "defeito" ou "limitação" do código se ele fosse útil, mas precisasse ser usado com cuidado.

## Essa mania que alguns usuários dizerem que o SO é melhor que o SOPT

Isso simplesmente não é verdadeiro.

Acesso muito o SO original (embora não participe) e há inúmeras respostas de péssima qualidade e muitas delas aceitas pelo OP porque resolvem um problema em particular.

Na verdade, por sermos uma comunidade nova e com menor volume de perguntas, conseguimos manter um padrão até mais alto de qualidade, em minha opinião.

Contudo, não quero dizer com isso que não precisamos melhorar. É quando alguém diz "tal coisa do SOPT não seria aceita no SO" ela está apenas no campo da opinião pessoal, muitas vezes na tentativa de provar sua tese sem um argumento consistente.

## Sobre a [questão em jogo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21774/227)

O OP não dá muitos detalhes, então não dá pra saber de onde vem a data, nem para onde ela vai.

Este é um caso muito comum em TI. Muitos colegas meu chegam perguntando como fazer algo. Eu pergunto o **porquê**. 90% das vezes a resposta é que **a própria pergunta está errada**.

Eu **desconfio** que se investigado a fundo descobriríamos que o OP não precisa inverter data nenhuma.

## Sobre a [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21795/227)

Pessoalmente eu não votaria nem a favor nem contra.

Não votaria contra porque ela funciona.

Não votaria a favor porque em certo sentido ela é desnecessariamente complexa para um problema que poderia ser resolvido de forma mais simples, como algumas outras respostas conseguiram fazer. Este pode ser um fator porque ela recebeu votos negativos.

## Validar ou não validar?

Como alguns já comentaram, validação não estava no escopo da pergunta. Entretanto, a preocupação do usuário que negativou a resposta é válido.

Na vida real, temos muitas exceções por falta de validação.

Pense também se você for fazer uma entrevista com código numa empresa como Google, Microsoft, Amazon, Facebook e cia. Escreva um método sem validar a entrada e será automaticamente desqualificado.

Enfim, é bom ter isso em mente e criar código "seguro" sempre. É algo que eu tento aprender todos os dias e muitas vezes enfrento a dura realidade de não ter feito isso adequadamente.

## Considerações

Temos todos os tipos de pessoas aqui.

É melhor aprender a conviver com pessoas que pensam diferente, e algumas vezes muito diferente, usando isso para agregar à sua experiência.

Comment: Excelente adendo à discussão. Também concordo que o OP certamente não precisa inverter data nenhuma, além de ter formulado a pergunta muito mal.

Comment: @HarryPotter Sim, sua solução é complicada e não somente por isso ela foi negativada por mim (e provavelmente pelos demais). Primeiro porque, quando comentei, ela estava usando uma expressão regular que também aceitava anos com dois dígitos. Isso levava a pensar que a função aceitava o formato curto de datas, que ignora os séculos. Porém, para a função date_create_from_format(), isso resultaria nos anos 1 a 99, e não 2001 a 2099, como se poderia esperar. Mesmo a expressão regular tendo sido corrigida, a solução em si pode ser considerada um code smell: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Answer (score 13):

Um interessante caso no Meta em que concordo (pelo menos parcialmente) com todas as respostas dadas até agora. Apesar de parecerem diferentes, elas tocam em particularidades de comportamento no site que vejo da mesma maneira.

Ainda assim, acho que algumas coisas, mais diretas, precisam ser tratadas.

## Sobre perfeccionismo

Há uma frase de [Carl Sagan](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Sagan) em [Cosmos](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_(livro)) que diz:

> Se você quiser fazer uma torta de maçã do zero, primeiro tem que criar o universo

É um ponto de vista interessantes sobre a hierarquia de conhecimentos e como observar um problema. O perfeccionismo, principalmente quando lidamos com o problema de outra pessoa, pode rapidamente se aproximar do pedantismo, criando um jogo nocivo de "eu sei mais do que você". Claro que vão existir respostas mais completas e mais relevantes, mas o problema é que **sempre** vão existir respostas mais completas e relevantes.

Claro existem graus diferentes de precauções e ninguém tem que dar respostas levando em consideração erros, ou exploits, absurdos que podem ocorrer sob condições muito específicas. A questão é que a linha que determina o nível "correto" de validações e prevenções é absolutamente **arbitrária e pessoal**.

Isso quer dizer que um post que responde ã pergunta mas que não faz todas as checagens que **você** faria não está necessariamente errado e, ao meu ver, não merece o downvote.

## Upvote pra lá, downvote pra cá

Não concordo com o ponto de vista de que se o upvote é um "concordo" implícito então o downvote é um "discordo". Existe uma diferença muito grande, em uma comunidade entre **não apoiar** e ser **contra**.

Votar contra uma resposta que não é tão completa quanto *você* gostaria é dizer que a opinião do resto é irrelevante e que a resposta não merece o apoio que teve, ou não teve, até agora. Com base, de novo, em uma condição absolutamente arbitrária do que você considera "completo".

A ideia do SO é que as melhores respostas vão para o topo. Isso acontece com base nos upvotes, e não porque todo o resto é afundado. Dessa forma, o comportamento do @PauloFreitas é essencialmente de imposição dupla do seu ponto de vista.

Ao apoiar o que você concorda e *ativamente atrapalhar* o que você discorda sua opinião se faz valer duas vezes, às vezes até contra o que pode é o consenso da maioria. Se você simplesmente discorda de algo, "não votar" é suficiente.

O downvote é pessoal e cada um usa da forma como quiser (desde que dentro das regras) mas, ao meu ver, utilizá-lo como forma de influenciar duplamente o site em prol do **seu** ponto de vista é impositivo demais.

Comment: Estava pensando aqui e se houvesse um meio de próximo da resposta aceita houvesse um link ou algum indicativo que apontasse para outra resposta que possa ter sido melhor reputada que aquela aceita? Em PHP é sempre preferível trazer os dados da forma mais correta possível para diminuir a sobrecarga do lado da linguagem. Com isso em mente, a resposta do @DouglasBernardino no *stack* em questão, apesar de não ter sido aceita, resolve um problema antes mesmo dele existir.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto A pergunta com maior reputação vai ser sempre a primeira, depois da aceita. Ela não é exatamente difícil de achar. Nem sempre que a resposta mais votada não for aceita vai ser por conta de malícia, ou ignorância, ou algum outro motivo, então não podemos presumir que ela é pior só por não ter sido a mais votada.

Answer (score 10):

De fato, podemos sim buscar excelência, mas existem diferentes caminhos para se obtê-la:

- Uns pisando na cabeça dos outros pra ver quem chega primeiro ao topo;
- Uns estendendo a mão pros outros para que cheguemos juntos ao topo.

Eu já encontrei essa atitude antes, tanto no SOen quanto aqui: você dá uma resposta bem intencionada, mas por conta de algum erro ou limitação na mesma outro usuário já vem sentando o dedo no botão do *downvote*, e ainda faz questão de frisar o `-1` nos comentários ao apontar seu erro (só faltando dizer: "uai, mas vocês não queriam que quem votasse contra comentasse?").

Muitas vezes quando a pergunta é sobre uma dúvida do OP, eu tento respondê-la mexendo o mínimo possível no código original de modo a salientar a causa raiz do problema, e só. Não refatoro o código inteiro para mostrar qual é a "melhor maneira". No entanto, vez ou outra aparece um jogando pedra porque "a solução é sub-ótima" ou "faltou considerar o caso X" [que nem fazia parte da pergunta], etc. E acham ruim se eu digo que não pretendo mexer mais na minha resposta (afinal, somos todos voluntários aqui, cada um contribui na medida que pode e quer).

Creio que se trata de pessoas sem traquejo social. Perfeccionistas, também, mas isso em si não é um problema: críticas são boas, nos fazem aprender, e dão a oportunidade para que juntos criemos um repositório de conhecimento amplo e acurado. Além disso, em ciências exatas não existe meio-termo, ou algo está certo ou está errado, e é bom cada um de nós que atua nessa área saber receber críticas ao nosso trabalho sem confundir com críticas à nossa pessoa. De modo que concordo com o Guilherme Bernal na afirmação de que os questionamentos daquele usuário foram pertinentes, mas também concordo com você no sentido que foram feitos de forma desnecessariamente áspera.

(digo **pertinentes**, não necessariamente **acertados** - como afirmei anteriormente, uma resposta *limitada* não é uma resposta *errada*, e uma resposta parcial é melhor do que resposta nenhuma)

A forma ideal de se fazer críticas, é claro, é de modo encorajador, e não na base da cacetada. Votos contrários, isso cada um usa como achar mais apropriado, se esse usuário achou necessário usar o voto para "reclassificar" as respostas de acordo com sua acurácia, eu diria que foi uma atitude acertada (embora eu pessoalmente prefira fazer isso votando positivo nas mais corretas, por vezes é necessário de fato negativar as erradas, não dá pra fugir disso). No fim das contas, portanto, minha sugestão é simplesmente ignorar esse tipo de comentário, aproveitando pra aprender com a crítica e - se quiser (mas sem a obrigação de) - alterando sua resposta. A menos é claro que o comentário seja "rude ou ofensivo" - o que não foi o caso aqui - a ponto de merecer sinalização.

> P.S. Em tempo: estou respondendo em caráter geral, como acredito que sua pergunta também o seja (ainda que tenha usado uma pergunta específica como exemplo). Boa parte do comentado não se aplica a esse caso particular, é apenas minha impressão acumulada nesses anos que venho participando do Stack Exchange.
>
> P.P.S. E antes que venham me dizer que estou tentando ser "político" ou "passar a mão na cabeça dos usuários", apenas estou me pautando no que é bem sabido na psicologia: as pessoas aprendem melhor quando são encorajadas do que quando são punidas. Se alguém discorda, e acha que no "mundo adulto" as pessoas têm de ser "mais casca grossa", respeito sua opinião, só não a compartilho.

Comment: Perfeita colocação. É de fato necessário não confundir uma resposta negativada com uma crítica pessoal: votos são reconsiderados na mesma proporção que respostas são melhoradas.

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Principalmente com a colocação sobre o uso irrestrito do downvote. Todos nós temos preferências ou filosofias a respeito de como as coisas devem ser feitas, sendo natural que votemos naquilo que concordamos. Ótimo, é pra isso que serve o upvote. Respostas podem ser julgadas pelo número de pessoas que concordam com elas. O downvote, então serve como um "viés", um peso extra que a resposta precisa superar se quiser obter destaque. Dar downvote irrestrito em tudo que você não concorda (ie, todas as outras respostas) é influenciar excessivamente a comunidade.

Comment: Isso me fez lembrar de uma célebre frase de um pequeno poderoso chuchu: "Tentar não. Faça ou não faça. Tentativa não há".

Answer (score 3):

Eu diria que o -1 deveria apenas ser usado em casos em que a resposta está realmente incorreta.

Se você acha que uma resposta apenas pode ser melhorada, deixe um comentário e/ou escreva a sua própria resposta. Se alguém já comentou sobre isso, vote a favor do comentário.

Também é indispensável votar a favor das respostas corretas, para que elas apareçam entre as primeiras.

Comment: Diria que o -1 também é bom para desincentivar quem se apodera de comments ou respostas alheias sem creditar ou sem postar como CW, entre outras funções educativas. O que não pode é levar pro lado pessoal, como eu vejo de vez em quando, que a pessoa "devolve" o -1 por uma questão alheia ao conteúdo da resposta. E só para completar, no meta é diferente: pode ser sinal de mera discordância de opinião.

Comment: Excelente resposta, resumida mais objetiva!

Answer (score 1):

Eu diria que:

A pergunta referente é sobre: ***Como inverter datas no PHP? Preciso inverter datas no PHP independente do formato de entrada, seja YYYY-mm-dd ou dd/mm/YYYYY.***, ou seja ele informou os dois formatos pretendidos, e não questionou se a data era válida em nenhum momento inclusive fez elogios a algumas respostas.

A respostas de:

- Kazzkiq: [Resposta](https://ideone.com/CGcW0h)
- Douglas Bernardino (perfeita já vindo formatado do banco),
- Flaviano Silva: [Resposta](https://ideone.com/mYehOk),
- Bruno Augusto: [Resposta](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5d7b524ad43273f65923cbb0988048e8beb00571) (apesar que o mesmo não levou -1) e
- Harry Potter: [Resposta](https://ideone.com/FO9nQt)

tiveram os mesmo resultado em testes feitos. Claro que não foi testado se o `input` era um `date` ou `datetime`, porque, na questão não teve essa imposição, apesar, que eu mesmo fiz uma edição (logo após o ***-1***) e acabei fazendo a alteração e mesmo assim de 3 votos positivos virou 3 negativos. O meus amigos da mesma pergunta também perderam pontuação, não falo de pontuação por achar que isso é o mais importante, mas, acredito que o empenho da galera foi importante e deixou as pessoas acertando ou errando se posicionarem em uma resposta.

Como foi dito por alguns ***-1*** só mesmo quando a resposta estiver errada, e eu concordo com esse posicionamento, porque, aos poucos vamos ajeitando a casa e para que isso aconteça precisamos o empenho de mais pessoas, mais contribuições, mais aprendizados.

A minha preocupação é dar oportunidade para que outros cresçam e apareçam, motivar é bom faz bem, mas, claro avisar de algum erro é importante, e existe uma maneira correta de fazê-lo.

Concordo com a verificação de data, mas, nessa pergunta não! nenhum momento foi questionado isso e as respostas não mereciam ***-1***. Quem colocou e apontou na sua resposta tal verificação, com certeza, terá os votos da comunidade, isso é certeza, sem nenhum momento desestimular os parceiros, como foi dito, ajudamos, porque, gostamos ...

Acredito que a única arma nossa é responder as perguntas, e apontar as falhas que possam ocorrer em nossas respostas, eu mesmo quando vejo uma resposta incoerente sempre tento fazer outro e apontar os erros possíveis.

Answer (score 0):

É bom evitar críticas ou responder a outras respostas. Isso é uma recomendação citada nas regras de uso do site.

Acredito que se mantivermos a recomendação, conseguiremos evitar esse tipo de transtorno.

Comment: Seria legal citar e linkar as regras que menciona.

Comment: @brasofilo, não são regras, são recomendações.

Não encontrei onde está o texto e não sei se ainda existe, mas sempre aparecia para mim quando eu respondia alguma questão.

Sou novo no site e percebi que o site oferece funções de acordo com o nível de uso de cada usuário. Acho que o texto com as recomendações é exibido para novatos somente. Não sei explicar, mas existe sim, ou ao menos existia até pouco tempo.